# TF2 transform can't find an actuall existing frame

Tags: python, ros, subscriber, slam, tf2-ros

In a global planner node that I wrote, I have the following init code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import copy
import tf2_ros
import time
import numpy as np
import math
import tf
from math import sqrt, pow
from geometry_msgs.msg import Vector3, Point
from std_msgs.msg import Int32MultiArray
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from nav_msgs.msg import OccupancyGrid, Path
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped, PointStamped
from tf2_geometry_msgs import do_transform_point
from Queue import PriorityQueue

class GlobalPlanner():

    def __init__(self):
        print("init global planner")
        self.tfBuffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
        self.listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self.tfBuffer)
        
        
        self.drone_position_sub = rospy.Subscriber('uav/sensors/gps', PoseStamped, self.get_drone_position)
        self.drone_position = []
        self.drone_map_position = []
        self.map_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/map", OccupancyGrid, self.get_map) 
        self.goal_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/cell_tower/position", Point, self.getTransformedGoal)
        self.goal_position = []
        self.goal = Point()
        self.goal_map_position = []
        self.occupancy_grid = OccupancyGrid()
        self.map = []
        self.p_path = Int32MultiArray()

        self.position_pub = rospy.Publisher("/uav/input/position", Vector3, queue_size = 1)
        #next_movement in
        self.next_movement = Vector3
        self.next_movement.z = 3
        self.path_pub = rospy.Publisher('/uav/path', Int32MultiArray, queue_size=1)

        self.width = rospy.get_param('global_planner_node/map_width')
        self.height = rospy.get_param('global_planner_node/map_height')

        #Check whether there is a path plan
        self.have_plan = False
        self.path = []

        self.euc_distance_drone_goal = 100
        self.twod_distance_drone_goal = []
        self.map_distance_drone_goal = []
        
        self.mainLoop()
```

And there is a call-back function call getTransformed goal, which will take the goal position in the "cell_tower" frame to the "world" frame. Which looks like this

```
def getTransformedGoal(self, msg):
        self.goal = msg
        try: 
            #Lookup the tower to world transform
            transform = self.tfBuffer.lookup_transform('cell_tower', 'world', rospy.Time())
            #transform = self.tfBuffer.lookup_transform('world','cell-tower' rospy.Time())
            #Convert the goal to a PointStamped
            goal_pointStamped = PointStamped()
            goal_pointStamped.point.x = self.goal.x
            goal_pointStamped.point.y = self.goal.y
            goal_pointStamped.point.z = self.goal.z
            #Use the do_transform_point function to convert the point using the transform
            new_point = do_transform_point(goal_pointStamped, transform)
            #Convert the point back into a vector message containing integers
            transform_point = [new_point.point.x, new_point.point.y]
            
            #Publish the vector
            self.goal_position = transform_point
        except (tf2_ros.LookupException, tf2_ros.ConnectivityException,  tf2_ros.ExtrapolationException) as e:
            print(e)
            print('global_planner tf2 exception, continuing')
```

The error message said that

```
"cell_tower" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

I check the RQT plot for both active and all, which shows that when active, the topic /tf is not being subscribe by the node global planner. Check the following image, which is for active
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Cai.png)

and this image is for all the node (include non-active)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeCK9.png)

But I have actually set up the listner, I have another node call local planner that use the same strategy and it works for that node, but not for the global planner
I'm not sure why this is.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a timeout to your `lookup_transform()` function call, as your transformation may not be available when you need it:

```
transform = self.tfBuffer.lookup_transform('cell_tower', 'world',rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(1.0))
```